# Get programmatically driver name of an interface

Tags: linux, networking

Is there a way  programmatically driver name of interface, except of parsing output of "ethtool -i interface_name"?

I would happy if it can be retrieved from a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query `sysfs` for it. Read the target of the `/sys/class/net/$interface/device/driver` symlink and take the part after the last `/`.

Example:

```
$ stat --format '%N' /sys/class/net/*/device/driver
‘/sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver’ -> ‘../../../../bus/pci/drivers/jme’
‘/sys/class/net/wlan0/device/driver’ -> ‘../../../../bus/pci/drivers/iwlagn’
```